# Android spinner avoid same data in list

Tags: android, spinner

I have two activities in Activity 1 when i click to a perticular item then the next activity launch with the spinner inside the clicked value,But the data is duplication in the below.How to avoid that duplication in my method of string passing.Please help me.

Activity 1

```
 View.OnClickListener enquiry_mercedez= new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // it was the 1st button
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), VehicleEnquiry.class);
                String proname="Mercedes S CLASS";
                intent.putExtra("vehicle", proname);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
          };
```

Activity 2

```
 final String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("vehicle");    
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            List<String> list;

            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            int index=list.indexOf(id);
            list.setSelection(index);
            list.add("Mercedes A CLASS");
            list.add("Mercedes B CLASS");
            list.add("Mercedes C CLASS");
            list.add("Mercedes S CLASS");

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: In your second activity you are adding the value which you have passed through intent from first activity. And that passed value you are adding two times in your arraylist items. That is why you are getting duplicate values.

Comment: While your retrieving your string data and it has a value `Mercedes S CLASS` from intent then why are you manually add it to in `VehicleEnquiry` class using this `list.add("Mercedes S CLASS");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get index of list which is pass from previous activity. After adding all values to list and then set it selected spinner value like:

```
final String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("vehicle");    
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        List<String> list;

        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Mercedes A CLASS");
        list.add("Mercedes B CLASS");
        list.add("Mercedes C CLASS");
        list.add("Mercedes S CLASS");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
        int index=list.IndexOf(id);

s1.setSelection(index);
```

Comment: Thats what i exactly neede but its not working,Please check my updated code to see how i updated your suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

Except for not opting to not do it manually, i.e. without:

```
String proname="Mercedes S CLASS";
  intent.putExtra("vehicle", proname);
```

In your 2nd activity, add the elements you want, and then check if `proname` matches any of those. Add it or don't add it to your list accordingly.

```
    final String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("vehicle");   
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Mercedes A CLASS");
    list.add("Mercedes B CLASS");
    list.add("Mercedes C CLASS");
    list.add("Mercedes S CLASS");

    boolean isInList =false;
    for (String string : list) {
        if(TextUtils.equals(string, id)){
            isInList = true;
        }
    }

    if(!isInList){
    list.add(id);
    }
//Rest of the code...
```